# i want this type of rating feature in gridview using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

can any body create a this type opf rating control using vb.net ajaxcontrol toolkit with mssql2005 and with retriction of one vote per person ... ?

[image]

if 10 people voted for the service using rating star then the average would be displayed in rating control..

Comment: This is not the type of question Stack Overflow is designed for. You should only ask specific questions which have a real answer. The answer to your question is, of course, "Yes, there are developers who could write this". What you are asking is for someone to write the code for you and that is not how SO works.

Comment: Sounds like a spec you received from a customer! -1

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you a very simple way that you can do it.

Render the stars, and the bar rating on a content div set, base on the content overlay with css that you can find here : http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/content_overlay_css/

Now the bars are hidden and when the user moves the mouse over the rating the bars are visible.

Its really very simple and the only think that takes your time to develop it the stars and the bars.

See this final example of how you can have the div with the bars hidden and open it on mouse over. http://snook.ca/testing/anton-test.html

With a little manipulation on the css you can make it as you like.